# ExtJS Managing windows and detecting front window

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an application that has many windows, which can be handled by corresponding buttons on a toolbar (sounds familiar right?!)

I currently have it so that if you click a button on the toolbar, if it is not ontop bring it to the front (`toFront`), if it is minimised, maximise it etc.

I want to be able to detect whether the window is the front most window...

Cheers

EDIT

TO further describe the situation: say if I have a window that is at the front, or "active". Then I click the corresponding toolbar button which minimises that window. I want to then find which window becomes "active".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To manage your Ext.Window instances use the Ext.WindowMgr singleton:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.WindowMgr

In a button's handler:

```
// Assuming 'winID' has been populated with the ID of an
// Ext.Window instance associated with the button.

win = Ext.WindowMgr.get(winID);
win.show();
Ext.WindowMgr.bringToFront(win);
win.maximize();
```

Comment: But I think this will run into the same problem I had with my solution, which is: how do you identify which window is at the front?

Comment: The Ext.WindowMgr singleton has a method getActive() which will return the current active window instance.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

Why not set an `activeWindow` property as part of the handler for clicking a button on the toolbar? If the window associated with that button is already at the front, there's nothing left to do.

Comment: That was my original idea, which works fine until you click a toolbar button to minimise the window. I still need to identify which window is topmost, or "active"

Comment: Aha. Then it should be a stack. Push a window on as it gets added, pop and place at the bottom if it gets minimised.